# I want to filter the result i get from an ajax request based in input data (like a search engine but my data comes from a server with JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Sample data

```
[
  {
    "messageId": "216",
    "message": "{\"message\":\"set archive as processed\"}",
    "systemTime": "2016-01-12 06:36:29"
  },
  {
    "messageId": "215",
    "message": "{\"message\":\"clear locTab\"}",
    "systemTime": "2016-01-12 06:36:29"
  }
]
```

Code

```js
function filterLogs() {

    console.log('Filtering logs...');
    var vlogID = $('#logID').val();
    var vkeyWord = $('#keyWord').val();
    var vkeyWord = $('#keyWord').val();
    var vfromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
    var vtoDate = $('#toDate').val();

$.each(function(i, v) {
    if (v.messageId == "215") {
        alert(v.message);
        return;
    }
});
    // if (vlogID == '419') {
    //     alert(message);



    // } else {
    //     // var result = {};
        //         result.logID = logID;
        //         result.keyWord = keyWord;

        //  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            // url: proxy + '/server/message/list.php?type='
            url: 'log.txt',
            data: 'logID:vlogID'



        })
            .done(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                var resultCol = 'green';

                var resultJson = result;
                if (resultJson || resultJson)
                    if (!JSON.parse(resultJson)) {

                        alert('error:> ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                    } else {




                        activities = JSON.parse(result);

                        $('#activities').render(activities);

                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $('.message').each(function() {

                                var input = JSON.parse($(this).text());
                                // alert($(this).text());
                                $(this).jsonViewer(input);
                            });
                        });
                    }

            })
            .fail(function(result) {
                alert('fail: ' + resultJson.succes + ' > ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                $infoField.html(JSON.stringify(result)).css('color', 'red');
            });
        console.log('Done Filtering...');

    }
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#filterLogs').click(function() {
        filterLogs();
    })
 });
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
     <div id="activities">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         
         <h3 id="messageId" class="panel-title"><span> : [ </span><span class="systemTime"></span><span> ] </span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body message">
         
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>


<ul>
  <li class="active">
   <input id="logID" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Log ID..."></li><a href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input id="keyWord" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword..."></li><a href="#"></a></li>
  </li>
  <li>
   <form>
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
     <input id="fromDate" type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" placeholder="From date" />
     <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
     <input id="toDate" type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" placeholder="To date"/>
    </div>

    <li><button id="filterLogs" type="submit" class="btn btn-success " href="/">Filter</button></li>
   </form>
   <a href="#"></a>
  </li>
  
  
  <li>
   
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: what is `v` in `filterlogs()` method? what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: i was trying different things so i forgot to delete them u can start looking from the ajax call. as u can see i recieve all my data from the ajax but i want only some of the data. like a filter